# Filter Elements from a list based on another list

Tags: java, java-8

I want to do this in **Java 8**

I have a `Boolean` list and another `Object` list, size of these two lists is always same. I want to remove all the elements from `object` list, which have `false` at the corresponding index in `boolean` list.

I will try to explain with an example:

```
objectList = {obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5};
booleanList = {TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE};
```

So from these list, I want to change `objectList` to

```
{obj1,obj3,obj4}// obj2 and obj5 are removed because corresponding indices are `FALSE` in `booleanList`.
```

If I have have do this in `Java 7`, I would do the following :

```
List<Object> newlist = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<booleanList.size();i++){
    if(booleanList.get(i)){
        newList.add(objectList.get(i));
    }
}
return newList;
```

Is there a way to do this in `Java 8` with lesser code?

Comment: Assuming random access lists, `List<Integer> resultList = IntStream.range(0, booleanList.size()).filter(booleanList::get).mapToObj(objectList::get).collect(toList());` is probably the most efficient you can get.

Comment: @AlexisC. it worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `IntStream` to generate the indices, and then `filter` to get the filtered indices and `mapToObj` to get the corresponding objects :

```
List<Object> newlist =
    IntStream.range(0,objectList.size())
             .filter(i -> booleanList.get(i))
             .mapToObj(i -> objectList.get(i))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @karthik, note that it's not actually the "lesser code" as you wanted. Your Java-7 solution is 178 bytes (including spaces) while this solution is 206 bytes ;-)

Comment: @TagirValeev I was not talking in terms of `bytes` :P, I was worried about getting answers like `you can write the same code in Java 8 also`. That is why added `lesser code`.